# What GPS IC do cell phones use

Tags: gps

I am experimenting using gps devices. I managed to utilize a [NEO-6M](https://store.roboticsbd.com/2043-large_default/u-blox-neo-6m-gps-module-robotics-bangladesh.jpg) gps module, but it only works when there is a direct 'optical' connection to a satellite (aka it does not work inside a home, under a roof or inside a bag. It needs to be outside)

So i wonder what sort of ICs do mobile phones use, since they can work inside buildings etc (even without a sim)? Is there a specific family of GPS ICs which is good and cheap that almost all phones use?

Comment: Please link to a datasheet for the device (and not an advert page). The pretty picture can be uploaded into your post. Critical information will be the antenna specification.

Comment: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.*

Comment: @Andyaka Oh right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the GPS in the phones are a) *really* integrated in the radio chipset and b) often software driven. I don't think a mere human could get his hands on such mass production/consumer tech.

By the way, and this could help with your module, most modules have their antenna undertuned so it will actually work at max performance only when in a plastic enclosure (the plastic is kinda part of the antenna system).

Of course, there are also just modules that suck:D

Comment: Mobile phones do not rely on GNSS (GPS is not the only satellite positioning system) alone. The cell towers provide corrections and extra information. Regardless, GNSS systems rarely work indoors. Also note that radiation from other electronics can easily mask the operation - circuit layout, antenna positioning all have a part to play.